# Using a single view for multiple NSManagedObjects

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobject

So I have a couple properties that are common across several of my Core Data entities. Notes, URL, etc.

I have a single view controller for editing this information, and I pass the Entity to it as a NSManagedObject

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject *editedObject;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Thing *thing;
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter=isEditingThing) BOOL editingThing;
```

And to actually get the object in a state I could make changes I would

```
if([editedObject isKindOfClass:[Thing class]]) {
  thing = (Thing *)editedObject;
  editingThing = YES;      
}
```

That way I can set the values on thing and save the managedObjectContext like normal.

However, this is crashing my application, but only if I enter and exit the View Controller for editing the field over and over again.

Which brings me to my question: What's the best way to handle using a single view controller to edit a common field on more than one Core Data Entity? Should I just set the Boolean and populate the correct entity property when I call the View Controller?

Comment: If your app is crashing when the view controller is entered and exited, there's probably a memory management issue -- you're either over-releasing or under-releasing. What do your Console and Debugger say when the crash occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both entities have a property called notes then change your property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id managedObject;
```

Then when you go to set it, you can just set it without caring what the object is:

```
[[self managedObject] setNotes:...];
```

As long as whatever you set `managedObject` to responds to the property `notes` it will work just fine.  If not, it will error out and you can test that easily.

You could go a more paranoid route and test if it responds first:

```
if ([[self managedObject] respondsToSelector:@selector(notes)]) {
```

but that is over protective since the only thing you would want to do that point is crash anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine your `thing` property is not getting retained because you're not using your accessor to set it. Change:

```
thing = (Thing *)editedObject;
```

to:

```
[self setThing:editedObject];
```

As to your bigger question, I think you need to provide more context. What do you mean by "edit a common field on more than one Core Data Entity"?

Comment: Thing has a property called notes (String), and Stuff has a property called notes (String).

I have a UIViewController that contains a simple UITextView for editing notes

Comment: This is what is causing your crash if you are releasing in the `-dealloc` like you are supposed to be doing.  My answer is focused on your other question.